# Array manipulation

Tags: array

I have two arrays of entires.

One for featured articles and another for the rest.

```
    {% set featuredArticles = entry.featuredArticles.article.all() %}
    {% set articles = craft.entries().section('newsArticles').all() %}
```

The max amount of featured articles the page can have is 2 - but the user might only select one or none. So I have written a condition to sanitise the array so there are not duplications i.e.

If a article is a featured article, remove it from the articles list.

I've got parts of it working but was wondering if there was a better way to do this? Any suggestions would be great.

```
  {# Get ARTICLES - featured and normal #}
    {% set featuredArticles = entry.featuredArticles.article.all() %}
    {% set articles = craft.entries().section('newsArticles').all() %}

    {# Featured articles #}
    {% if featuredArticles|length %}
      <div class="featured_articles">

      {# 
      *** TWO FEATURED ARTICLES ***          
      #}
      {% if featuredArticles|length == 2 %}

        {% for featuredArticle in featuredArticles %}
          {% if featuredArticle is defined and featuredArticle is not empty %}
            {% include "_includes/blocks/news_card" with { block: featuredArticle, featured: true } %}
          {% endif %}

          {# Sanatize featured articles from artciles array #}
          {% set url = featuredArticle.url %}

          {% for article in articles %}
              {% if article.url == url %}
                {% set articles = articles | slice(0,loop.index) %}
              {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
      {# 
      *** ONE FEATURED ARTICLES ***          
      #}
      {% elseif featuredArticles|length == 1 %}
        {% include "_includes/blocks/news_card" with { block: featuredArticles|first, featured: true } %}
        
        {% set url = featuredArticles|first.url %}
        
        {% for article in articles %}
            {% if article.url == url %}
              {% set articles = articles | slice(0,loop.index) %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% include "_includes/blocks/news_card" with { block: articles|first, featured: true } %}
      {% endif %}
      </div>
      {# 
      *** NO FEATURED ARTICLES ***          
      #}
    {% else %}
      <div class="featured_articles">
        {% include "_includes/blocks/news_card" with { block: articles[0], featured: true } %}
        {% include "_includes/blocks/news_card" with { block: articles[1], featured: true } %}
      </div>

      {# Sanatize articles array #}
      {# [2:] omits the first two itterations of the array #}
      {% set articles = articles[2:] %}
    {% endif %}
```

---

Thank you for your amazing answer - Its really helped!

There was a small part that I had missed out about housing the featured articles in a div and the articles in a div for styling them.

I managed to write some if/else to do this adapting your code:

```
  {# Get ARTICLES - featured and normal #}
    {% set featuredArticles = entry.featuredArticles.article.all() %}
    {% set articles = craft.entries()
        .section('newsArticles')
        .id(['not']|merge(featuredArticles|column('id')))
        .all()
    %}

    {% set articles = featuredArticles|merge(articles) %}

    {% for article in articles %}
        {# Open featured article div on first loop #}
        {% if loop.first %}
          <div class="featured_articles">
        {% endif %}
        
        {# Set featured articles #}
        {% if loop.index <= 2 %}
          {{ include("_includes/blocks/news_card", {
              block: article,
              featured: loop.index <= 2
          }) }}

        {# Close featured Loop #}
          {% if loop.index == 2 %}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
          
        {% else %}

        {# Open articles div #}
        {% if loop.index == 3 %}
          <div class="news_articles">
        {% endif %}

          {{ include("_includes/blocks/news_card", {
              block: article,
              featured: loop.index <= 2
          }) }}          

          {% if loop.last %}
            </div>
          {% endif %}

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Again thank you so much for your help on this - there is alot to learn about what can be done in twig when it comes to manipulating data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to ensure that the `articles` array doesn't include any entries that are already in `featuredArticles`, you can just add that as a condition to the second query:

```twig
{% set featuredArticles = entry.featuredArticles.article.all() %}
{% set articles = craft.entries()
    .section('newsArticles')
    .id(['not']|merge(featuredArticles|column('id')))
    .all()
%}
```

Then you don't have to do any of that complicated array manipulations.

Beyond that, the template is very long and complicated but doesn't appear to be doing a whole lot. If I'm not mistaken, all you're trying to do is display a list of articles with two featured articles at the top, and either one or both of those could be manually selected in the `featuredArticles` list. Right?

In this case, you can massively simplify the template. This is all you need:

```twig
{% set featuredArticles = entry.featuredArticles.article.all() %}
{% set articles = craft.entries()
    .section('newsArticles')
    .id(['not']|merge(featuredArticles|column('id')))
    .all()
%}

{% set articles = featuredArticles|merge(articles) %}

{% for article in articles %}
    {{ include("_includes/blocks/news_card", {
        block: article,
        featured: loop.index <= 2
    }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Sidenote: The `include` tag is deprecated and will stop working in Twig 3 / Craft 4, best to replace that with the `include` function.